# With VMware Workstation, how can I SSH from the host to a guest with NAT?

Tags: windows-7, ssh, ubuntu-12.04, vmware-workstation, nat

My host is Windows 7 with VMware Workstation 10. I am running an Ubuntu 12.04 guest that is connected to an NAT network. How can I set up the network so that I can SSH from the host to the guest? I assume it has to do with port forwarding?

Comment: What's your current virtual network configuration? Do you have a network adapter attached to the NAT network?

Comment: @DanielB Yes, `eth0` is connected to NAT on the guest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VMware Workstation creates virtual interfaces on the host. One for the host-only network and one for the NAT network.

(This is one point where VirtualBox is different)

So you only need to determine the IP-address of the guest.

Comment: Do you mean the IP address of `eth0` on the guest?

Comment: It works now. I don't know why it didn't before, even though I'm sure I tried that before.

Comment: I went through my command history... It turns out I was spelling my username wrong in the SSH command!